# Django incomplete migration of table with multiple foreign keys

Tags: django, foreign-keys, django-migrations

Django version: 4.1.2

After heaving the following table defined in the model:

```
class Tasks(models.Model):
    name_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    duration_int = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    ...
```

the next two tables have been defined:

```
class Metiers(models.Model):
    name_text = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    ...

class TasksProperties(models.Model):
    task = models.ForeignKey(Tasks, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='task_relation')
    metier = models.ForeignKey(Metiers, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='metier_relation')
    ...
```

doing the migration, the metier is not created inside the SQL table, but the rest:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('simo', '0009_alter_specialdays_day_date'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Metiers',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('name_text', models.CharField(max_length=50)),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='TasksProperties',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('workload_mh', models.IntegerField(default=8)),
                ('task', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='simo.tasks')),
            ],
        ),
    ]
```

Is there any reason, why metier is not taken into account?

Update on 27/11/2022:

So, it still not clear why it was not working because I believe the structure is correct; therefore I did some try-on-errors and finally the migration is complete, although the reason is not obvious. See below the resolution:

Step 1) Remove the migrated TaskProperties class from models and do a migration

Step 2) models.py was updated as

```
class TasksProperties(models.Model):
    workload_mh = models.IntegerField(default=8)
    metier = models.ForeignKey('Metiers', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='metier_relation')
```

It resulted that the "metier" as foreignkey was visible in SQL after the migration.

Step 3) Adding the "task" as well, the migration dropped the following question:

```
class TasksProperties(models.Model):
    workload_mh = models.IntegerField(default=8)
    metier = models.ForeignKey('Metiers', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='metier_relation')
    task = models.ForeignKey(Tasks, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='task_relation')
```

*It is impossible to add a non-nullable field 'task' to tasksproperties without specifying a default. This is because the database needs something to populate existing rows.
Please select a fix:

1. Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
2. Quit and manually define a default value in models.py.
   Select an option: 2*

Then after updating the model.py adding default value **default=0** to "task" the migration was successful:

```
class TasksProperties(models.Model):
    workload_mh = models.IntegerField(default=8)
    metier = models.ForeignKey('Metiers', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='metier_relation')
    task = models.ForeignKey(Tasks, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='task_relation', default=0)
```

Why is this "defualt" value is needed?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try these three commands:

```
python manage.py makemigrations appname

python manage.py sqlmigrate appname 0001

python manage.py migrate
```

And see if it solves

Comment: Well, this is what I meant as migration. And as it seems in the DB, the migration happens but only one particular field is not considered...